# Simpler zeta zeros

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Is it true that

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^{y}n^{-1/2-iy}}{\zeta(1/2+iy)}=1$$

? Below is a plot of $$\sum_{n=1}^{y}\dfrac{1}{n^{s}}\text{for }s=\dfrac{1}{2}+iy$$

[image]

set against its smooth analytic continuation. Is this less expensive computationally for large $y$?

## Notes

```
x = 1/2; Plot[{Re[\!\( \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(y\)] 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(x + I\ y\)]]\)], 
Re[Zeta[x + I y]], Im[\!\( \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(y\)] 
\*FractionBox[\(1\), SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(x + I\ y\)]]\)], 
Im[Zeta[x + I y]]}, {y, 0, 30}]
```

*Included with subsuperscript boxes for ease of reading when pasted into Mathematica.*

## Update

To address [Mercio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17445/mercio)'s point:

[image]

The plot of the quotients (as posed in the original question) is very messy (includes grid-line at $1$), and clearly doesn't "tend to $1$" in the strict sense of the meaning. Perhaps if zeros of each function were excepted, it would make more sense. Suggestions of re-phrasings of the question are welcomed!

## Update 2

Question now rephrased - improvements suggested by [Raymond Manzoni](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21783/raymond-manzoni):

Is it true that
 $$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\zeta(\dfrac{1}{2}+iy)+\dfrac {1} {2}\dfrac {1} {[y/\pi]^{1/2 + iy}} - \sum_ {n = 
  1}^{[y/ \pi]}\dfrac {1} {n^{1/2 + iy}}=0?$$

which [John M](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12642/john-m) has more or less answered below.

Comment: $\sum n^{-s}$ diverges when $\operatorname{Re}s<1$ (in particular, when $s=1/2+iy$). So, no, you have to use [reflection formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/586870/) or something like that to define $\zeta(s)$ in the 'interesting' area.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too - and I'm sure you do to get accurate values, but the usual definition still seems to generate some sort of result...

Comment: @GrigoryM: The upper bound for $n$ in the summation depends on $y$ in the given formula. It is not therefore (to me) a priori impossible that this makes some sense for some reason.

Comment: Thanks - yes - I understand that it has to be calculated in the way you mention. That is not my point. The point is that y is the top value as JJ says - if it is any larger, no sensible plot results.

Comment: Since the upper bound of the summation is the same $y$ as the imaginary part of $s$, it seems that your sum, though well-defined, has very little to do with the actual zeta function.

Comment: Please explain why it mimics the analytic continuation?

Comment: @martin: "which becomes far truer to its analytic continuation as $y$ gets larger" -- Do you have a plot of this or something?

Comment: `x = 1/2; Plot[{Re[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(y\)]
\*FractionBox[\(1\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(x + I\ y\)]]\)], Re[Zeta[x + I y]], Im[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 1\), \(y\)]
\*FractionBox[\(1\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(x + I\ y\)]]\)], Im[Zeta[x + I y]]}, {y, 0, 
  30}]`

Comment: Included with subsuperscript boxes for ease of reading when pasted into _Mathematica_

Comment: @martin: Ah, sorry, I missed that there were 4 graphs in the picture in the question. The smooth ones are the real and imaginary parts of real zeta and the wiggly ones are your sum?

Comment: Ah, I understand the question now. This looks somewhat similar to, say, exponential regularization of (divergent) series, so maybe it has some meaning...

Comment: Yes - included actual for comparison.

Comment: I guess another to phrase it is: Is it true that $$\lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^y\frac1{n^{\frac12+iy}}}{\zeta(\frac12+iy)} = 1$$

Comment: Yes - this is what I meant ;)

Comment: @martin: Just a suggestion: Maybe you should modify the question to ask if the sum approximates the real zeta and make no mentions of zeros at all at this point.

Comment: If it's true, which you have an indication of I think, it's still not very useful for finding exact values of the zeta zeroes, since you can't get arbitrary precision with this method.

Comment: Will do - corrections on the way...

Comment: Your denominator $\zeta(1/2+iy)$ may be approximated using the Euler Maclaurin expansion as exposed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378803/zeta-function-zeros-and-analytic-continuation) with the finite sums $S_y(N):=\sum_{k=1}^Nk^{-1/2-iy}$ as long as $\;2\,\pi\,N >\ |y|$. The next 'error terms' contribute nearly $\dfrac 1{\sqrt{y}}$ in your specific case $N=y$ (which satisfies the previous inequality!). The two links at the end should provide, I hope, interesting additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your notes - the link you provided is interesting - as are the links within it :)

Comment: uh ... guys ? this is false for a stupid reason : unless the zeroes of the approximation are exactly the same as the zeroes of the zeta function (which would be very unexpected), the quotient of the two functions takes values as close to 0 and infinity as you want, so it can't have a limit. A valid question would be if the series is convergent for nonzero $y$ maybe ?

Comment: I agree that the zeros are almost definitely not the same. Your point is a very valid one. Still, the essence of the question remains, however un-rigorously it has been posed.

Comment: Would you advise altering the question accordingly?

Comment: I don't think the quotient of any such oscillation functions can tend to $1$ in the strict sense of the meaning, can they?

Comment: Oh that's right, and I'm the one guilty of luring you into changing the question. I'll leave it to you and other people to rephrase it, I'm drinking beer!

Comment: Enjoy!! ;) ....

Comment: Glad that my link(s) helped @Martin and yes you should be in trouble with your division as explained by mercio (note that the subtraction doesn't have this problem). 

Let's add that a more accurate result should be obtained (I think) with your finite sum replaced by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\left[ y/\pi\right]}'\frac 1{n^{1/2+iy}}$$
with $[y/\pi]$ for round$(y/\pi)$ and ' meaning that we replace the last term of the sum by half of its value.

Comment: I don't really understand how this helps - do you think you could add this as an answer of sorts?

Comment: Is this equivalent to 
$$-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{(y/\pi)^{1/2+iy}}+\sum_{n=1}^{[y/ \pi]}\dfrac{1}{n^{1/2+iy}}$$, or have I misunderstood? Im can see that $$\sum_{n=1}^{y/ \pi}\dfrac{1}{n^{1/2+iy}}$$ makes a difference.

Comment: More exactly :
$$-\dfrac 12\dfrac 1{[y/\pi]^{1/2+iy}}+\sum_{n=1}^{[y/ \pi]}\dfrac{1}{n^{1/2+iy}}$$ The precision should be pretty good and much better than $\dfrac 1{\sqrt{y}}$. I'll try to provide more details in an answer later. The answer can only be partial : I don't think that your division may converge (even with $y\mapsto \alpha y$ at the upperbound) but replacing it with a difference can give interesting things!

Comment: Whoops missed that rounding bit! Question now updated as per your suggestions - I look forward to reading your answer! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please allow me to write what *is* true:

We have the estimate in the critical strip ($s = \sigma + it$):
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n < N} n^{-s} + \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} + O(N^{-\sigma}).$$
Therefore,
$$\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right) = \sum_{n < t} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}+it}} + O(t^{-1/2}).$$
So
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \left | \zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right) - \sum_{n < t} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}+it}} \right| = 0.$$

You may also be interested in this [recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5295).

ADDED LATER (at Daniel's request):

First, we assume that $\sigma = \operatorname{Re}{z} > 1$, so that the sum $\sum n^{-s}$ converges absolutely. We can write the sum $\sum_{n \geq N} n^{-s}$ in terms as a Stieltjes integral,
$$\sum_{n = N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} = N^{-s} + \int_N^\infty x^{-s} \;d(\lfloor x \rfloor),$$
where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.  Now we can integrate by parts to get
$$\int_N^\infty x^{-s} \;d(\lfloor x \rfloor) = -N^{-s+1} + s \int_N^\infty x^{-s-1} \lfloor x \rfloor \; dx.$$
Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$, i.e. $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.  We get
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n < N} n^{-s} + N^{-s} + \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} - s \int_N^\infty x^{-s-1} \{x\} \;dx.$$
Since $\{x\} < 1$, the integral on the right actually converges for all $\sigma = \operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$, i.e. we get an *analytic continuation* of the Riemann zeta function from $\sigma > 1$ to $\sigma > 0$.
In fact, for $\sigma>0$, we can bound the integral,
$$\left| \int_N^\infty x^{-s-1} \{x\} \;dx \right| < \frac{N^{-\sigma}}{\sigma}.$$

Anyway, this is all standard material available in any book on analytic number theory.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, especially on the estimate in the critical strip?

Comment: @DanielR - Hi I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for providing an explanation for the proof - to be honest, I am not sure that I fully understand each step (though I understand in it in a broad conceptual sense), but I shall persevere with the links you provided, and hopefully gain a deeper understanding as a result!

Comment: @martin - If there are particular steps that are confusing, then I can point you somewhere that explains better.

Comment: Thank you - I will have a good look and focus my questions carefully ! :)

Comment: Thanks again John, and the bounty could have gone either way. It was more or less a coinflip decision.

Comment: in $\zeta(1/2+it) = \sum_{n < t} n^{-1/2-it} + \mathcal{O}(t^{-1/2})$ you forgot  the (important) $\frac{N^{1/2-it}}{-1/2+it}$ term

Comment: @user1952009 - I did not forget.  I set $N = t$ and so it is subsumed into the error term.

Answer (score 15):

**(Updated)**
As a complement to John M's proof (+1) I'll add some 'visual clarifications' (whatever this may mean...) about the behavior of the finite sum of $\zeta\;$ for a large but fixed ordinate $y\in\mathbb{R}^+$ :
$$\tag{1}S_y(N)=\sum_{k=1}^N\frac 1{k^{\,1/2+iy}}$$
Let's suppose that $y$ is the first ordinate of a nontrivial zero larger than $10000$ and represent all the partial sums $\,S_y(N)$ for $\;N=1\cdots 3183=[y/\pi]\;$ in the complex plane :

[image: N=3183]

The cross at the middle is at the origin ($z=0$) while '1' represents $z=S_y(1)=1$ and '2' $\;S_y(2)=1+\dfrac {2^{-iy}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and so on up to '3183' representing $\;S_y(3183)$ very near to $0$ again.
$$-$$
The picture shows figures looking like [Cornu (or Euler) spirals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral). Let's justify this :
the sum $S_y(N)$ is obtained by addition of terms $\,\displaystyle \frac 1{k^{1/2+iy}}=\frac {e^{-iy\log(k)}}{\sqrt{k}}$.
The next term will thus be $\,\displaystyle \frac {e^{-iy\log(k+1)}}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.
Now for $k\gg 1$ the denominator will change only slightly while the change of phase of the numerator will be $\;\delta=-y\;(\log(k+1)-\log(k))=-y\,\log(1+1/k)\approx -\dfrac yk$.

$\delta\approx -\dfrac {y}k$ gives a special role to the values of $k$ such that $\dfrac yk\approx f\pi$ with $f$ integer :

- for $f=2m$ (i.e. $k=\left[ \frac y{2m\pi}\right]$) we have $\,\delta\approx -2m\pi\,$ : for values of $k$ near of $\left[ \frac y{2m\pi}\right]$ the terms have nearly the same phase and their addition will nearly give a straight line (see f=2, f=4, and so on on the picture)
- for $f=2m+1$ (i.e. $k=\left[ \frac y{(2m+1)\pi}\right]$) we have $\,\delta\approx -(2m+1)\pi\,$ : for values of $k$ near of $\left[ \frac y{(2m+1)\pi}\right]$ two consecutive terms nearly cancel each other and that's what is happening in the middle of the 'nodes' f=1, f=3, f=5 and so on.

Let's zoom the center of the final node $f=1$ :

[image: zoom]

The line nearly crossing the origin is obtained with the term $k=3183=\left[ y/\pi\right]$ while the line at its left and right came from  $k=3182$ and  $k=3181$ respectively. The value $S_y(3183)$ itself is far out of the picture (say $12$ or more times higher) while $S_y(3182)$ is far at the bottom on the other side. Taking the middle of these two values should bring us not too far from our target even if the different partial sums $S_y(N)$ don't really 'go down to $0$' ! (they merely turn around it)

All this explains (but doesn't prove) that an excellent approximation for $\zeta$ may be obtained (near the zeros at least) with the formula :
$$\zeta\left(\frac 12+iy\right)\approx -\frac 1{2\,[y/\pi]^{1/2+iy}}+\sum_{n=1}^{[y/ \pi]}\frac{1}{n^{1/2+iy}}$$

(numerically the absolute error appears majored by $\dfrac{2.5}{y^{3/2}}$ in the range $(10,10000)$, and probably for larger values, while the initial sum from the question was majored by $\dfrac{0.9}{y^{1/2}}$)

Now what happens when we continue adding terms after $\dfrac y{\pi}$ ? Well the difference of phase $\,\delta\,$ will become smaller than $\pi$ and we will turn round and round and obtain an ever growing ball of black wool :-) (illustration for $N=10^7$)

[image: black ball]

This discussion was rather qualitative and may be followed by these [more general and precise expansions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1695494/21783) provided not only for $\,N=\left[\dfrac y{\pi}\right]\,$ terms but also for $\left[\dfrac y{e}\right]$ terms with $0<e<2\pi$.

But the story doesn't end here and Riemann himself found that you didn't need to compute the sum of $[y]$ terms (or $\left[\dfrac y{\pi}\right]$ or $\left[\dfrac y{2\pi}\right]$ or whatever) but that
$\left[\sqrt{\dfrac y{2\pi}}\right]$ terms were enough, at least if you accept some correction terms!  [(Riemann-Siegel formula)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356824/how-does-one-calculate-the-amount-of-time-required-for-computation/358941#358941)
and [basic facts about Riemann $\zeta$ and the Euler Maclaurin formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378803/zeta-function-zeros-and-analytic-continuation/379810#379810).

As a fun alternative you may examine with care my first picture : notice that the distance from f=1 to f=3 is $1$, that the distance from f=3 to f=5 is $\dfrac 1{\sqrt{2}}$ and think 'Symmetry'!

All the pictures presented here were produced interactively using the (old) [CSE applet](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/CSExplorer/CSExplorer.htm) that I created for Matthew R. Watkins (see the comments in case of problems).
[Vitaliy Kaurov kindly provided nicer pictures using Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48894/partial-zeta-curlicues/48917#48917).

Comment: $\Large\text{Yay!}$

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting perspective, and thank you for the links.

Comment: Glad you liked my curlicues! :-)

Comment: Wow - great visuals & nice to have an explanation that focuses on the partial sum aspect of the question - it is a great insight into how it all works :) Just out of interest, what program did you model this behaviour in?

I am in a bit of a quandary as to whose answer to accept, as John M has given the proof and yours has provided in-depth details - please advise! :/

Comment: (I was considering a diplomatic approach would be to accept John M's answer since yours had been awarded the bounty, but in truth, I believe that together they form a more complete answer - it is a pity multiple answers can't be accepted on this forum.)

Comment: I have seen something similar before [here](http://www.stanford.edu/group/journal/cgi-bin/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Erickson_NatSci_2005.pdf), which I presume is analysing partial zeta sums along similar lines. I should be very interested in knowing how to go about modelling this in _Mathemetica_. Could you suggest where I might begin?

Comment: @martin: Please go for the diplomatic approach, John provided a proof while I was more interested by the intuition for the partial sums. The referenced Erickson's paper is excellent, I didn't read it in details but used his $\gamma(s)$ notation in my other [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356824/how-does-one-calculate-the-amount-of-time-required-for-computation/358941#358941) (the ref. is missing I'll add it). I don't use Mathematica sorry ; I used the CSE [here](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/CSExplorer/CSExplorer.htm).

Comment: Select 'Finite zeta sum' in the (possibily hidden) combobox at the bottom left. Set Y offset=10000 (return) and click on 'Next zero'. After that change the number of terms at the bottom and zoom with the scrollbar at the top (click on the arrows rather than using the thumb.)

Comment: I tried `y = 10000; ListLinePlot[
 Table[{Im[E^(-I y Log[k])/Sqrt[k]], Re[E^(-I y Log[k])/Sqrt[k]]}, {k,
    1, 3183}]]` (in _Mathematica_) which gives a very muddled plot compared to your one above...

Comment: ... I will go with the diplomatic approach as advised, but, to be honest I think I have learned a great deal more in the short term from your answer (in particular , due to the support you provided in the mean time), but I can't help thinking that the art of answering a question is gauging the level of the asker, and tailoring the answer accordingly. Perhaps when I eventually become a little more competent, I shall more fully appreciate the value of John M's answer...

Comment: ...I do not understand what you mean by 'combobox' btw - nor can I find any ref to CSE, even though I have read the link you provided - please excuse my ignorance on these matters! :/

Comment: @martin: Well the Critical Strip Explorer is the applet at the bottom of the page and if you click at the lower left part you should see this ![list deployed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/db4WR.png) (it is an applet from around 2001 so that modern browser support may be poor sorry...). There are no other reference than on this page (or the java source code) but I'll answer questions you could have about it.

Comment: (of course java has to be activated if you want the applet to work!)

Comment: Can't seem to activate unfortunately. Though owing to your very clear explanation, I don't have any questions at this point - the only reason I would like to model them is just to play with the parameters really! :)

Comment: @martin (I'll try tomorrow using different Windows browsers, I am presently using Safari on an old powermac)

Comment: @martin [Mathematica or Wolfram Language version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48917/13)

Comment: Excellent work @VitaliyKaurov ! (antialiasing makes things nicer)

Comment: @martin: Concerning the CSE there is indeed some security 'blocking' in recent versions of Windows (7 and more and possibly Vista) or java (that I'll suppose installed and activated; btw you should notice the same problem with the linked applet by Pugh). To make it work I modified /configuration panel/java (32 bits)/security panel/add url and added the [CSE link](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/CSExplorer/CSExplorer.htm) (a better way may exist...). Anyway Vitaly proposed you a useful alternative so enjoy! Cheers,

Comment: Great - that worked - thanks - what a fantastic resource! Seems not to work in Firefox though for some reason - Chrome is OK though :)

Comment: I don't see how one can notice that the distance from f=1 to f=3 is 1 and that the distance from f=3 to f=5 is 1/√2 by examining the first picture. In fact exact centers of the spirals at f=3, f=5, etc are not given by the partial sums, although there are good approximations for f=1 as you say. In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172535/do-partial-sums-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-lie-on-a-curve) I claim that the partial sums don't exactly lie on a Cornu or Euler spiral.

Comment: I should have said that your good approximation for f=1 also works for f=3 and f=5, but unlike f=1 you can't improve it using Euler Maclaurin AFAIK.

Comment: @user258279: "I don't see how one can notice that..." Well I did around year $2000$ and this came as a very pleasant surprise. I "visually confirmed" that in the linked [follow up](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/358941/21783) (my third picture). I don't claim that the center is exact (and think that precision should decrease with $f$ but increase with $y$) and the discussion about the Riemann Siegel formula in the link as well as Carl Erickson's paper may interest you. I found your question interesting (the first upvote was mine) but didn't think at any curve fitting better...