# Do partial sums of the Riemann zeta function lie on a curve?

Tags: riemann-zeta

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805396/simpler-zeta-zeros/815480#815480) shows a diagram representing a series of partial sums of the zeta function in the complex plane, and says that it shows figures looking like Euler spirals. I have plotted a similar diagram: an enlargement at the origin [shows the partial sums (black) superimposed on a Euler spiral (green) plotted between appropriate centres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Q9g.png). The partial sums are close to, but not exactly on the spiral.
I have been unable to find a curve which could replace the Euler spiral and give an exact match.

Comment: @user1952009 I get this [link](http://chrisjones.id.au/z5.png). How is that relevant?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you want to understand the spiral appearing when plotting $\zeta_N(s) = \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$ for $N \in \{1\ldots 10^4\}$.

There is a plot of $\zeta(s)-\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1}$ in blue and $\zeta_N(s)$ in green, the red cross being $\zeta(s)$ at $s=  1.4+8i$.

Since $\zeta(s)-\zeta_N(s) = \sum_{n = N+1}^\infty n^{-s} \approx \int_N^\infty x^{-s}dx =\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1}$ it explains why the two spirals are so close.

[image]

What to say more ?

- You can get a better approximation of $\zeta(s) - \zeta_N(s)$ with more terms (in $N^{-s},N^{-s-1},\ldots,N^{-s-j}$) see the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#Par_la_formule_d.27Euler-Maclaurin).
- Also the blue and green spirals get very close when $N$ is large enough
- The more $Im(s)$ is large, the more the green plot is messy for $N$ small and the more $N$ needs to be large for making a nice spiral appear.

Comment: That's nice, but the blue function is not really a spiral curve, it's a series of 10000 points to which you have fitted a spiral-like curve somehow. I am looking for a continuous curve which fits the green points exactly.

Comment: @shortcipher The blue curve is $\zeta(s) - \frac{x^{1-s}}{s-1}$ for $x \in [1, \infty)$

Comment: @shortcipher And why would you want to fit exactly the partial sums ? In that case look at $f_s(A) = A^{1-s}+ s\int_1^A \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1}dx$ it is a differentiable curve such that [$f_s(\lfloor A \rfloor) = \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor A \rfloor} n^{-s}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula)