# How do I calculate the values of $\zeta(0.5+ie^x)$ for large $x$ ?

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta

In wolfram alpha the values of $$\zeta(0.5+ie^x)$$ closed to zero then How

do I know the real values  of $\zeta(0.5+ie^x)$ for large real number $x$ ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: The paper by Gourdon and Sebah ["Numerical evaluation of the Riemann 
Zeta-function"](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/zetaevaluations.pdf) and this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356824/how-does-one-calculate-the-amount-of-time-required-for-computation) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your favorite analytic continuation and calculate it. That's one way.

For instance, you might use that
$$ \zeta(s) = (1 - 2^{1 - s})^{-1} \eta(s)$$
where
$$ \eta(s) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n - 1}}{n^s},$$
which simply converges at values $s = \frac 12 + it$.

If you're asking how others go about it, many use a so-called [Approximate Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_formula) (or series accelerations of it or the $\eta$ function). See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69718/riemann-siegels-approximate-functional-equation-for-fixed-t-and-res%E2%89%A01-2) for a bit more about the approximate functional equation.

Comment: @thank you for your answer, is n(s) able to calculate :n(0.5+ie^x) for large x ?

Comment: Yes, of course. What I call $t$, you call $e^x$. I'm not promising that it converges quickly, but it converges all the same.

Comment: but should be know that w.alpha also used n(s) but didn't up to calculate it

Comment: Ok. What does that have to do with anything?